# CSS3 background-size property causing extreme performance issues in ff5

Tags: firefox, css, gradient, linear-gradients

I've been putting a page together today and thought that I'd implement a striped background using CSS3. All seemed fine in all browsers except for Firefox. (I'm using 5.01 but checked in 5.0 too)

The code is simple enough:

```
    body {
    background-color: #ebeced;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%,
    transparent 25%,transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-size:6px 6px;
    }
```

Works great in Chrome and opera but it practically crashes FF.

Obviously I know that I can achieve this effect with a repeating background image but I was wondering if anyone else had a similar issue or is it just teething problems with CSS3 again ;)

Testing in jsfiddle produces the same issues, I didn't make a fiddle as I didn't want to be responsible for crashing you!

Oh and it's not a slow pc issue, I'm on an i7, 8gb ram, blah blah.

I believe it to be a problem with the background-size property as if you increase this or remove it entirely then the issue is resolved, however it's not suitable for me unless I can use background-size.

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should report.  At a guess, what's happening here is that tiling the gradient is really slow, but it's hard to tell without an actual testcase.  I just tried your snippet in Fx4 and Fx5 and a nightly, and none show any performance issues.  But note that this may be OS-dependent and I'm on Mac right now.  If you do report a bug on Mozilla on this, please add ":bz" to the cc field.  Or if you can point me to your fiddle showing the problem I can report the bug for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm on w7 at the moment, I'll just fire up snow leopard and check it in there first so I can send a more complete bug report. I'll make sure I cc .bz.

Comment: I can confirm that it's not affecting FF on Mac, Writing up bug now.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure I know what the problem is.

The performance problem is not very apparent for me, but I am on a new quad-core.  What I do see is that when I create a blank page and put that css in there, then if I resize the browser, the redraw is a little clunky.

The problem comes from the fact that you are combining drawing CSS3 gradients with tiling that gradient at a very small size (6px).  This means that for every 1000 sq.px of page real estate, the gradient will tile 27,777 times [1000/6 squared].  That is a ton!  A smart browser would draw the gradient once and then tile it.  It seems like Firefox may draw the gradient every time.  If that is the case, that would indeed be a bug.  If I modify the background size property to something larger, like 20px then I no longer see a performance problem, but others will.  If you don't want your users experiencing these kinds of problems, I would say that you should stay away from this combination because slower computers will still have problems when you don't see any.

The easy fix is to not use the css3 gradients.  Just create an image - browsers are good at tiling those.  Even with images, it is sometimes better to use larger images ...

---

Early versions of Netscape Navigator used to ignore backgrounds if they were smaller than 40x40 pixels.  I remember discovering that the cause of the bug I was trying to solve, and realizing that even though it seemed nice to be able to use a 1x20 image for a background because that would be the minimum file size, it was not the best choice for performance because it creates much more rendering work for the browser.  Instead, I create a larger 50x20 version of the image.  The effect is the same, but it saves some processing time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding...

```
-moz-background-size:6px 6px;
```

...to your css?

Comment: is that even a legitimate property? i cant see reference to it anywhere. + it doesn't work!

Comment: With some CSS3 properties, you prepend `-moz-` for compatability (similar to `-webkit-`,`-o-`,`-khtml-`). I'm sorry that this didn't work for you, but yes. It is a legitimate property: **http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/**

Comment: I see!, thanks for letting me know about that, however background-size without the prefix seems to work for FF but its horribly slow and ends up crashing it! -moz-background-size doesnt seem to be picked up even by the latest version of ff.